# FIRMessaging Delegate Error

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I tried to add FIRMessagingDelegate but Xcode gives an error

`Cannot find protocol declaration for FIRMessagingDelegate.`

I imported FirebaseMessaging and it gives no errors. I checked pods and it seems fine.

```
Installing Firebase (3.2.1)
Using FirebaseAnalytics (3.2.0)
Using FirebaseInstanceID (1.0.6)
Installing FirebaseMessaging (1.1.0)
```

How I try to implement;

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <UserNotifications/UserNotifications.h>
#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>

#if defined(__IPHONE_10_0) && __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= __IPHONE_10_0
@import UserNotifications;
#endif

@import Firebase;
@import FirebaseInstanceID;
@import FirebaseMessaging;

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate, FIRMessagingDelegate>
```

I could not find any solution, what could be the reason for error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pods are updated so I tried it again. Now it works without problem.

Comment: what did you include in the pod file? anything else besides pod 'Firebase/Core' and pod 'Firebase/Messaging'?

Comment: No, just Firebase/Core and Firebase/Messaging.